# new PerformanceObserver(cb).observe({ type: 'paint', buffered: true }) doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, cross-browser, web-performance

```
new PerformanceObserver((list) => {
  list.getEntries().forEach(console.log);
}).observe({ type: 'paint', buffered: true });
```

```
performance.getEntriesByType('paint').forEach(console.log);
```

These two snippets log matching paint entries in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera. However, in Safari 15.3 the `PerformanceObserver` approach doesn't log at all (the callback isn't invoked), but the `getEntriesByType` approach does log the "first-contentful-paint" entry. It seems that Safari [supports PerformanceObserver.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/observe#browser_compatibility) and [supports the PerformancePaintTiming API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformancePaintTiming#browser_compatibility). **Why does the above `PerformanceObserver` approach not work in Safari?**

If there is a bug in Safari do you think that `getEntriesByTypes` without a PerformanceObserver's [buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/observe#parameters) is OK to use instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being worked in Safari. Follow this bug: to see it: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=225305

> If there is a bug in Safari do you think that getEntriesByTypes without a PerformanceObserver's buffer is OK to use instead? Thanks.

The issue with not having `buffered` option is you can miss observations that happened before you registered the observer. See here where I noticed inconsistency with whether events were measured or not: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals/pull/139

Comment: To address the issue of "you can miss observations that happened before you registered the observer" we (1) added an Observer with a buffer and (2) run getEntriesByType('paint') for prior entries just on Safari.